# Searching or filtering on a multi value field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a MySQL database with a table that contains 2 importants fields **title** and **age_range**.

That table saves documents  like this `'45;60'` for documents designed for users between 45 and 60 years old, `'18;70'`  for users between 18 and 70 years old and so on...

Now I would like to fire the query  `'test'` on the field **title**  with the filter `'18;50'` for the field **age_range** that will return all documents matching `'test'` with the age range field contained in this interval including the 2 cases above for example.

For instance, I use Logstash to index my data.

How can I achieve this?

Any treatment to do while indexing my data with logstash?

Any filter, tokenizer to use while indexing using ES analyzer?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can split the data as two fields with grok filter. To ship data to Elasticsearch, you can use logstash jdbc_streaming input and elasticsearch output firstly. And you configure your input like below:

```
input {
    jdbc_streaming {
        # Configuration of jdbc 
        # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-jdbc_streaming.html
    }
}

filter {
    # Split the field as separeted two fields
    grok {
        match => { "age_range" => "%{NUMBER:age_range_top};%{NUMBER:age_range_bottom}" }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        # elasticsearch output configuration
    }
}
```

Analysis depends on your search method. How can you want to search these fields. Range fields is necessary default one if you want to do only range filter. But you should do some work about `title`. For example you can follow [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html) example to handle autocomplete.